# E[X|Y]=E[X] When X and Y are Independent -- Proof from Book Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof in a book for the following Theorem:

Let $Y \in L^1 (\Omega, A, P)$ and suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then
$E[Y|X]=E[Y]$.

Proof: Let $g$ be bounded Borel. Then $E[Yg(X)]=E[Y]E[g(X)]$ by independence.
**Thus taking $f(x) = E[Y]$ for all $x$, in Theorem (1), we have the result by** (2).

Theorem (1) states that for $X$ a $\mathbb{R}^n$ random variable, with $Y$ a random variable, $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$ if and only if there is a borel measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Y=f(X)$.

Theorem (2) states that if $Y \in L^1(\Omega, A, P)$ and $\mathscr{G}$ a sub $\sigma$ algebra of $A$, then there exists a unique element of $E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$ of $L^1(\Omega, \mathscr{G}, P)$ such that $E[YX]=E[Y|\mathscr{G}]X]$ for all bounded $\mathscr{G}$ measurable $X$.

I'm not able to figure out how (1) and (2) are being used here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem (2) states that ${\rm E}[Y\mid X]$ is the unique integrable, $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable satisfying ${\rm E}[Y Z]={\rm E}[{\rm E}[Y\mid X]Z]$ for all bounded, $\sigma(X)$-measurable $Z$.

So let us show that ${\rm E}[Y]$ satisfies these requirements. It's obvious that ${\rm E}[Y]$ is integrable and $\sigma(X)$-measurable (why?). So let $Z$ be a bounded, $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable. Then by Theorem (1) we have $Z=f(X)$ for some Borel measurable function $f$, and hence by independence we have
$$
{\rm E}[Y Z]={\rm E}[Yf(X)]={\rm E}[Y]{\rm E}[f(X)]={\rm E}[{\rm E}[Y]Z]
$$
which is the wanted equality.